# Laravel: use logged in user data on another website

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a laravel website and it has a blog that works with wordpress as a backend.

the laravel website is on the root domain:
www.example.com

and the wordpress blog is on the sub domian:
blog.example.com

I need to use the logged in user's data in the blog.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a SAML solution, either using :

- [PHP Saml](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml)
- [Laravel's implementation of the PHP SAML library](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2)